# Jquery problens in atob(). I make a image in canvas and want to send to server in PHP

Tags: jquery, image, canvas, resize

I am learning JS and Jquery. I'm developing a upload's page and i am having problens with canvas and atob(). I can send, but the image is too heavy in server. A image has 500kb, when i send to server it increases to 1.3Mb.

My code in jquery:

```
function uploadImage($form){
    // Criando variaveis
    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //formelement
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Faço primeiro o carregamento da foto senão aparecerá 0(zero) de width e height
    var img_loaded = document.getElementById('img_loaded');

    var natural_width = img_loaded.naturalWidth;
    var natural_height = img_loaded.naturalHeight;
    var maxWidth = 800; // Max width for the image
    var maxHeight = 600;    // Max height for the image
    var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio

    function diminuir_largura(){
        if(natural_width > maxWidth){

            ratio = maxWidth / natural_width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            new_height = natural_height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            new_width = natural_width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = new_width;
            canvas.height = new_height;
            ctx.drawImage(img_loaded, 0, 0, new_width, new_height);

            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            img_loaded.src = dataurl;                                           
        }
    }


    if(natural_width == natural_height){
        diminuir_largura();
    }else{
        if(natural_width > natural_height){
            diminuir_largura();
        }
    }

    var blobBin = atob(dataurl.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
      array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    var file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {name: 'avatar.png'});

    formdata.append("image", file); // blob file

    // Enviando tudo pro php
    request.open('post', 'uploading.php');
    request.send(formdata);
}
```

I appreciate any help...

Comment: atob is definetly going to make the data bigger as it only uses letters ans numbers and few other characters to represent binary data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: ok... But there is another way to send the image?

Comment: You could sent them as they are directly

Comment: How would that send? As I'm learning, so I do not know much. And the PHP dont make upload.